# Error with htaccess url rewrite with another url

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to make a redirect with specific variables and format.
Here is the format of the url I want:

```
https://example.com/1234/http%3A%2F%2F5external-link.com
https://example.com/1234/http://external-link.com
```

I have my htaccess setup like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ index.php?id=$1&url=$2 [L,NE]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: no rules before ?

Comment: Only basic setup.

Comment: According to https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, it should work for both of those URLs. Show us your “only basic setup” as well, show the full .htaccess / rewrite configuration.

Comment: The htaccess code above is current, its all I have in there. I had already tested on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ however when I have code on site I get a 404 error code.